# What kind of database schema is systemdbserver.systebdb.dbo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

So, I'm risking some downvotes here.  But, not being incredibly familiar with SQL Server, sometimes I see what appears to be a database schema like follows:

```
systemdbserver.systemdb.dbo.tablename
```

I'm familiar with what `dbo` is, but can any of you tell me if, for example, `systemdbserver` is the name of the Database Server (as the name implies), then `SystemDB` is a `database`, and then finally `DBO` is the `schema`?  Is this a correct interpretation of the above?

Comment: `[server].[database].[schema].[object]` 4-part identifier

Answer (score 2):

Simply `[server].[database].[schema].[object]` is 4-part identifier.

See also [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

> 1 = Object name
>
> 2 = Schema name
>
> 3 = Database name
>
> 4 = Server name

If you don't like to deal with such long names you can use [`SYNONYM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx)

```
CREATE SYNONYM MyEmployee
FOR Server_Remote.AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee;
```